# Azure Mobile Service Patch entity not working

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have an azure mobile service, in my controller I have a patch method, but when I call the service from the client or the web (using try this out) the UpdateAsync method doesn't work, the patch Delta parameter doesn't have the right data I think, also if I call patch.GetEntity() all fields are null except the id.
This is my code:

```
    public Task<MyEntity> PatchMyEntity(string id, Delta<MyEntity> patch)
    {
        return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
    }
```

I am passing the Id in the uri and the entity in the body (using try this out):

```
{
 "user_id": "sample string 1",
  "group_id": 2,
  "doctype_id": 3,
  "prefix": "sample string 4",
  "lastnum": 5,
  "enabled": true,
  "rowguid": "05f3f914-c9d2-493d-8559-0a5e3f616664",
  "id": "sample string 7",
 }
```

Please, advice.

Comment: How are you calling Patch?  Try logging the outgoing client request with Fiddler, or paste the exact call you are using on the "try it out" page. Alternatively, you can use Postman for Chrome to make the REST calls.

Comment: I updated the post, now I show the json I am posting to the service..

Comment: It's probably an issue mapping the body contents to the Delta object. If the MyEntity field names don't match what you're sending, that could cause a problem. You should also use camelCasing for your entity names.

Comment: Yes, I have created a test entity with more simpler fields and it works fine. But I have an existed db I can't change field or table names at this point, what approach I can use in order to match the posted json with my entity?

Comment: Try this tutorial, which shows how to connect to an existing database: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/